# Good Modules to build Booking system using drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I want to build booking system for spa related website using drupal. Which are the good contributed modules please suggest. 
***Condtions:***

1. Customer can book the spa with his details
2. Customer can cancel booked his spa
3. All records should be update in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Most of that could be achieved in a default Drupal 7 installation I believe since the requirements/conditions are relatively basic.

**Views** goes without saying.

**Date** is pretty much essential for your purposes as it provides a nice date picking interface.

**Link** is useful if you have fields that need to link to nodes.

**Panel** for configuring layouts of pages.

**Webform** is great for making forms, definitely useful for a booking system.

[Some more examples can be found here.](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/top-drupal-7-modules-winter-2014-edition)